# Emacs ERC automatic Nickserv Identification for IRC

Tags: emacs, irc

I have this in my emacs .init file:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/.ercpass")
(global-set-key "\C-cef" (lambda () (interactive)
                       (erc :server "irc.freenode.net" :port "6667"
                            :nick "nick")))
```

What line do I need to add to "~/.emacs.d/.ercpass" so that my password is automatically identified?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: I just grepped all Lisp files in the Emacs master branch, and there is no such thing as the word `ercpass`.  Please provide a link and/or further explanation regarding how it is that an `ercpass` file was chosen by the original poster to hold a password for `erc-mode`.  In addition, please set forth the contents of `.ercpass` so that we can see what it contains -- it's okay to redact any sensitive information.

Comment: It looks like the Emacs wiki has the answer, beginning at the section entitled **Identifying yourself to Nickserv**:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcNickserv

Comment: Thanks, that link you supplied had the answer!

Answer (score 1):

@lawlist already pointed years ago to the resource https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcNickserv#toc4 which contains the answer the OP needed. But I go about this in a different way, so I thought that I would list various options for future users.

In all cases, you want, in your init file:

```
(setq erc-prompt-for-nickserv-password nil)
```

- **OP's method:**

Have in your init file:

```
(load "~/.ercpass")

(setq erc-nickserv-passwords
          `(freenode (<nick> . ,freenode-password)))
```

and create a file ~/.ercpass with:

```
(setq freenode-password <password>)
```

- **A very similar method, keeping everything in the init file:**

```
(setq erc-nickserv-passwords
          '(freenode (<nick> . <password>)))
```

- **An alternative method with [authinfo](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusAuthinfo):**

You can have the login info in your ~/.authinfo.gpg file.

Add a line with:

```
machine irc.freenode.net login <nick> password <password>
```

This is the method I use because it identifies the nickname faster and the password is protected.

Note that for any of these methods, you can have as many nicknames and passwords on as many networks as you want. Simply add more lines as appropriate (and of course, replace freenode by whatever network you are actually interested in).